# pointers & function call within method

Tags: c, pointers

I'm getting couple compile errors and I cant figure them out.It's probably something simpe, but I dont cant figure it out. I'm guessing reference to pointers have to changed, but I dont know what exactly. I was trying to change pointers but it would still give errors.I would appreciate any help. These errors are:

```
  passing argument 1 of 'compare' from incompatible pointer type
  expected 'struct person *' but argument is of type 'char *'
  passing argument 2 of 'compare' from incompatible pointer type
  expected 'struct person *' but argument is of type 'char *'


  struct person *insert(struct person *head, char *personName, int personAge, int        (*compare)(struct person *a, struct person *b)) 
  {  
    struct person *new;

    new = (struct person*)malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    if(new == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't allocate memory!");

    new->name = personName;
    new->age = personAge;  

    if(head == NULL)
    { 
      new->next = head;
      head = new; 
    }

    else
    {
      while(head != NULL)
      head = head->next;

      //compile errors
      if(compare(new->name,head->name) < 0)
      { 
        new->next=head;
     head->next=NULL;
      }

      else
      {
        head->next = new;
        new->next = NULL;
      }
    }//else  
      return head;

  }//method



  //----------------------------compare--------------------------------//
   int compare(struct person *a, struct person *b)
   {
      int result = strcmp(a->name, b->name);
      return result;
   }
```

Comment: Just a tip: Don't ever name a variable `new`. If you ever want to use C++ with this codebase, you will have a hell of a time trying to change the name of the variable.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III: I wanted to write the very same comment. Anyway, the same goes for other C++ keywords too, like `delete`, `class`, `template` etc.

Comment: There's no point in the `result` variable,  you should just `return strcmp(a->name, b->name)`, and use more `const` for the pointers. Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C.

Comment: i was gonna change return statement later :) but i dont see the point of making pointers const. and with malloc i thought you always suppposed to cast return value

Answer (score 2):

just try to substitute `compare(new->name,head->name)` to `compare(new, head)`

Answer (score 2):

Should not you use `compare(new,head)` instead of `compare(new->name,head->name)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `compare` function takes 2 `person` pointers but you're passing it 2 `char` pointers (names).